# Type-safe interface when instantiated/returned from enum (Java)

Tags: java, generics, interface, enums

Suppose we have an Automobile object:

```
public interface Automobile {
}
```

We also have a couple of different cars (is-a), one with an auto transmission and one with a manual transmission:

```
public class FordExplorer implements Autmomobile {
    public static void shiftIntoPark() {
    }
}

public class Porsche911 implements Autmomobile {
    public static void shiftInto1stGear() {
    }
}
```

Now, let's say we have an enum Garage, which stores these Automobiles:

```
public enum Garage {
    FORD {
        public Automobile getCar() {
            return new FordExplorer();
        }
    }, PORSCHE {
        public Automobile getCar() {
            return new Porsche911();
        }
    };

    abstract public Automobile getCar();
    }

}
```

Is there a "best practice" for this implementation (or one similar to it) that is type-safe (i.e. so that the return type of the getCar() method for the FORD only includes the shiftIntoPark() method and, likewise, the return type of the same method for the PORSCHE only includes the shiftInto1stGear() method)?

Comment: One way would be to keep `Automobile`, but instead of using it as a marker interface, declare all "shift" methods. Then the specific classes would either implement them, or throw a `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: If I understand you right, then no. If the method has to be able to return both cars, then it has to return a type that matches both of them. So any method declared in that type will have to be implemented by both of them.

Comment: @Mena - I'd say it's **not** best practice to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` since it violates Liskov Substitution Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @AdamMichalik I agree, didn't say it was best practice.

Answer (score 2):

The type returned by Garage.getCar is Automobile, it's not going to expose any of these park methods. Since the shift methods are static you're not going to get polymorphic behavior out of them, they have to be called on the specific classes.

It is likely you are expecting the thing using the Automobile to be too smart about how it's using the Automobile, thereby defeating the purpose of using an interface. The point of using interfaces or superclasses like this is so that the program can manipulate objects at a high level without caring about implementation details, letting the different object implementations take care of themselves. An analogous toy example might be an Automobile that exposed a park method, where that park method was implemented differently by the specific subclass according to its specific needs.

(Or alternatively get rid of the interface altogether, since driving a Mustang is not anything like driving a Corolla it might not make sense for them to share an interface.)

Interfaces and superclasses help provide a high-level interface and hide implementation details so they can be contained locally and don't leak out all over the rest of the program. Work out how you want the object to be used, which defines the interface you want to expose, and what you want the object to take care of on its own.

Comment: I’d see it the other way round. A Mustang and a Corolla differ when it comes to driving, but since this question is centered around a garage (in the sense of a storage), there is no actual difference, the only thing that may matter for storage are size constraints. However, as soon as the op tries to make a real storage out of it, rather than an infinite source of new cars, an `enum` becomes inappropriate anyway…